# Best approach to scheduled events in Node.JS

Tags: java, node.js

I'm currently writing a browser based game where events occur in real time - as an example of this, take Farmville, where a crop only grows after a particular length of time.

Running a method every second is a bad idea, and so the better setup would just be that when the server is asked for data it works out how long has elapsed and run the calculation for all of those seconds at once.

I'm writing the main application server in Node.JS, but would it make more sense to do these calculations in the Node.JS server itself or to allocate a new Java server which would just be in charge of doing these calculations?

Comment: By new Java server, do you mean a different machine?

Comment: Sorry, someone there suggested I post here. Should I delete the old post?

Comment: I just mean another application :)

Comment: So by "server" you really mean "application?"

Comment: Yes, should my game logic be part of the main application or its own?

Comment: Which programming language do you want to write the game logic in?  What database are you going to use to store the user and events data?

Comment: Will probably write in either Node or Java, and will be using MongoDB.

Comment: Mongodb appears to be well-supported by both Java and Javascript.  Node is Javascript.  So I guess it comes down to personal preference.  I would personally write it in Javascript using node, but that's my personal preference.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Would you say it would be better in the same or a different server, to separate the load?

Comment: Without knowing *far* more about your application, it's not clear what would or wouldn't make sense. Right now it sounds like you're comparing one server running a node.js game loop versus one server that runs node.js just to invoke a separate server running a java game loop, which is obviously pointless if you have nothing other than the game loop for the node.js server to do.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach with events is to have a persistent Queue of Jobs.

Your webserver dosnt perform the Job, it just adds one to the Queue. Ie. 'Harvest Crops at 10:15'

A second worker process, pulls Jobs from the Queue and peforms whatever logic. Ie 'update db with new crops level and send user an email'

The reason for this architecture is that the webserver only has a limited number of threads to answer incomming requests. If you use them all up waiting for timed events your webserver will slow down.

Additionally a Queue allows you to spread the work over multiple machines.

Im not super familair with Node. But it seems like there are some plug and play solutions out there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904093/worker-queue-for-nodejs